# How can I get joystick data using glfw?

Tags: c++, glfw, joystick

I am trying to get joystick input using glfw. I am using nintendo pro controller.

The code seems pretty simple and straightfoward, but I can't seem to get accurate joystick data.
I used

```
int axesCount;
const float *axes = glfwGetJoystickAxes(GLFW_JOYSTICK_1, &axesCount);
```

and tried to access joystick data by
`axes[0], axes[1], axes[2], and axis[3]`

glfwGetJoystickAxes gave me an accurate number for axesCount, which is 4.
But even if I moved the joystick the axes array always returned **1.52590219e-05**.

Below is the whole code for my appliation

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


int main()
{
   GLFWwindow *window; 

   // initialize 
   if (!glfwInit()) {
       return -1;
   }

   // create window and its opengl context 

   window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OpenGL Project Tutorial", NULL, NULL); 

   if (!window) {
       glfwTerminate(); 
       return -1; 
   }

   // make the window's context current 

   // loop untill the user closes the window 
   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

       // render OpenGL here 

       int present = glfwJoystickPresent(GLFW_JOYSTICK_1); 
       std::cout << "Joystick/Gamepad status: " << present << std::endl; 

       int axesCount;
       const float *axes = glfwGetJoystickAxes(GLFW_JOYSTICK_1, &axesCount);


       if (1 == present) {
            
           //std::cout << "Number of axes available: " << axesCount << std::endl; 

           std::cout << "Axis 1: " << axes[0] << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Axis 2: " << axes[1] << std::endl; 
           std::cout << "Axis 3: " << axes[2] << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Axis 4: " << axes[3] << std::endl;

           std::cout << std::endl; 
           std::cout << std::endl;
           std::cout << std::endl;
       }


       // swap front and back buffers 
       glfwSwapBuffers(window);

       // poll for and process events 
       glfwPollEvents(); 

   }

   glfwTerminate(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

It didn't matter whether I put

```
int axesCount;
const float *axes = glfwGetJoystickAxes(GLFW_JOYSTICK_1, &axesCount);
```

inside the while loop or not.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried it with another game controller than the Nintendo Switch Pro Controller? (BTW: `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` is missing after the comment...)

Comment: Yes i did. I was initially using XK-12 joystick from PI engineering, and it gave me the same error.

Comment: The code example seems to work in my case, tested with multiple controllers (Switch/Xbox/PS) on Windows 10. `#include "pch.h"` was removed. (And the check could be changed to: `if (present && axes != NULL && axesCount >= 4) {...}`.) - Does your controller get recognized [here](https://gamepad.e7d.io/) or in another joystick tester tool?